# How to unit test the asyn call in knockout by mocking promises

Tags: mocking, promise, mocha.js

I have the following code which I want to unit test

```
    var _getPrevOrNext = function(forward) {

        self.someService.getNextPage(args).
            done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              //some code
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               //some code
            });
    };
```

How can we mock the service call, as in unit testing don't want to back end?

I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon`.

Comment: Is `forward` a callback function called at the end of the execution?

Comment: yes forward is a callback function.